# How do I know if cider is hard or not?

Tags: alcohol

There's some apple cider in the fridge and (given as I don't usually drink apple cider) I don't know if its turned "hard" or not. There are no visible bubbles, but it is kinda fizzy. I am not sure whether the alcohol or fizz comes first, and google has all but failed me in this regard. I am especially worried about this because I'm under 21. If anyone has an answer, it would be most appreciated (I apoligize if this question doesn't quite fit here, but I this is the most related Stack Exchange I could find)

Comment: I would recommend [Beer, Wine & Spirits Stack Exchange](http://alcohol.stackexchange.com/) instead. If you'd like to move this there, you can flag it for a moderator can migrate it, or you can delete it yourself, and open another there.